Cannot connect to SQL Server in Azure Data Studio
I keep getting an error that there is an existing profile with the same same server info in the same group.
I was expected to log in as usual after logging into the system. I haven't changed anything on the backend so I don't understand why this is happening.


From the text error, I'm seeing two ways to resolve this issue :

You opened a connection to the same server while a connection was already established [i'm seeing two connections on the left tab]
==> the solution in this case is either delete one of the two connections, or double check the connection parameters in case of any mistake

In the connection parameters , try putting 'Trust Server Certificate' to "True". Worked previously with Azure Data Studio and this used to solve most of my connections problems.


P.S: We would like to get more context of this error, elements like : is this your first time connecting to the server ? if yes, did the connection work smoothly before, any recent changes in Infra or network ?
All of these elements would impact potentially your ability to connect to the server.
